# splitting and merging the string in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function.. actually let me quote the example:

```
def return_path(item_id):
    # return item_id

print return_path(1234567) # 67/45/23/1234567
print return_path(1) # 00/00/01/1
print return_path(12345678) # 78/56/34/12345678
```

I have been able to figure out for writing it in straight order(but its not entirely correct)

```
def return_path(item_id):
    path = ''
    path.extend(re.findall(r'.{1,2}',str(item_id) ,re.DOTALL))
    path.append(str(item_id))
    return os.path.join(*path)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the relationship between the integer and the string returned?

Comment: So I want to generate a path based on item id... which has 3 levels of heirarchy..

Comment: What knows the rules for the hierarchy?

Comment: So, 1234567 returns 67/45/23/1234567 if id is 1 it returns 00/00/01/1 .. 12345678 returns 78/56/34/12345678

Comment: So how would 1234 be formatted here?

Comment: it should be 00/34/12/1234

Comment: And 123? That's an odd number of digits < 6.

Comment: 00/03/12/123
basically, pad 0 in the front :0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a few rules:

- Only the right-most 6 digits count.
- Numbers with < 6 digits need padding; add zeros to the left until you have an even number of digits, with an odd last digit before the 5th digit.
- The numbers are paired and then are reversed from highest to lowest.

This'll do all that:

```
def return_path(item_id):
    path = []
    # pad with zeros, grab only the last 6 digits
    str_id = format(item_id, '06d')[-6:]
    # any extra zero pairs at the start are in the path first
    while str_id.startswith('00'):
        path.append('00')
        str_id = str_id[2:]
    # for an odd number of padding zeros, swap out the 0 to the last digit
    if str_id[0] == '0':
        str_id = str_id[1:-1] + '0' + str_id[-1:]
    # grab digits in pairs starting at the end
    path += [str_id[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(str_id) - 2, -1, -2)]
    path.append(str(item_id))
    return os.path.join(*path)
```

Demo:

```
>>> return_path(1)
'00/00/01/1'
>>> return_path(12)
'00/00/12/12'
>>> return_path(123)
'00/03/12/123'
>>> return_path(1234)
'00/34/12/1234'
>>> return_path(12345)
'05/34/12/12345'
>>> return_path(123456)
'56/34/12/123456'
>>> return_path(1234567)
'67/45/23/1234567'
>>> return_path(12345678)
'78/56/34/12345678'
```

Comment: yeah.. also 12345 is off.. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I'd group the last 6 by 2s, reverse it, pad with zeroes, then group that by 2s and use that as your final path.

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n):
    groups = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return [''.join(group) for group in itertools.zip_longest(*groups,
                                                              fillvalue='')]

def return_path(item_id):
    item_id = str(item_id)
    concat_path = ''.join(list(grouper(item_id[-6:], 2))[::-1])
    zero_padded_path = "000000" + concat_path
    final_path_groups = grouper(zero_padded_path[-6:], 2)
    return '/'.join(["{}/{}/{}".format(*final_path_groups), item_id])
```

DEMO

```
In [85]: return_path(123)
Out[85]: '00/03/12/123'
In [86]: return_path(1)
Out[86]: '00/00/01/1'
In [87]: return_path(123456789)
Out[87]: '89/67/45/123456789'
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I changed the `if` statement because the extra space actually needed to be before the last digit, not the first one. That way it returns `00/03/12/123` rather than `00/23/01`.

```
def return_path(item_id):
    if len(item_id) % 2 != 0:
        item_id = item_id[:-1] + ' ' + item_id[-1]
    path = ['{:6}'.format(item_id)[-6:].replace(' ', '0')[x-2:x] for x in range(2, 7, 2)]
    path.reverse()
    return '/'.join(path) + '/{}'.format(item_id.replace(' ',''))
```

#### Explanation

The `if` clause makes sure that the string is an even number of characters by adding a space before the last digit.

Here's an explanation of that one really long line (excluding the `path =`)

```
['{:6}'.format(item_id)[-6:].replace(' ', '0')[x-2:x] for x in range(2, 7, 2)]
[                                                     for x in range(2, 7, 2)] Begins list comprehension
 '{:6}'.format(item_id)                                                        Gets item_id with added spaces if needed
                       [-6:]                                                   Gets last 6 characters
                            .replace(' ', '0')                                 Changes all spaces to 0's
                                              [x-2:x]                          Slices [0:2], [2:4], [4:6] (see list comprehension)
```

So that returns the last 6 digits sliced into 2-character segments. Then it `.reverse()`s them, and finally it returns that list joined with a `/`, with the `item_id` appended to the end.

**EDIT 2:** If you want to be really fancy, you can replace everything after the `if` statement (not including the `item_id =` line of course) with this:

```
return '/'.join(['{:6}'.format(item_id)[-6:].replace(' ', '0')[x-2:x] for x in range(2, 7, 2)][::-1]) + '/{}'.format(item_id.replace(' ', ''))
```